# How to accept multiple image files but only one video file with input html tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently trying to implement a way for users to add images or 1 video to their post on this social media website i am working on, however, I cannot seem to add the logic for a user to only add multiple images to their post OR 1 video to their post. Would anyone have any examples of this logic by chance?

Comment: two different buttons maybe? upload images / upload video

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do something along the lines of

```
if (str_contains(userInputFilename, '.mp4')) {
    return;
} else {
    allowMultipleImages
}
```

I would personally lean more towards using php for this because I find it easier to do things like `str_contains()` in php vs javascript